# What is the best use case for Neo4j Spring Data?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Neo4j for my social network analytics, I'm wondering whether do I need to use Spring Data. All the properties of a node are dynamically provided by the client, In spring data, the Neo4j Node is always mapped to an object which means the schema of the node is immutable. So does spring data can only be used when the schema of each node is immutable, or do I miss something?

I am already working in a Spring Environment.

Answer (score 0):

SDN is easiest for mapping. If you need control of the graph, e.g. writing in highly concurrent scenarios where you don't want to modify detached Objects to be mirrored to the graph, you can simply reach through to Neo4j with

```
@Autowired
Neo4jTemplate template;

....

template.query("my cypher query", parameters);
```

To get your updates persisted, or look up nodes directly.

Comment: I want to be able to dynamically add/remove properties and relationships from nodes, Is this suitable to use SDN?